# Infinite scrolling behavior on up scroll in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scroll

I am trying to implement a scrollable div containing a list. This div also has a top and bottom marker div. On reaching bottom marker, the list gets appended with a random number and the div is re-rendered. This creates an infinite scroll kind of effect.

However, I want to do the same effect on up scroll. Essentially, when the top marker is in view, I want to prepend the list with some random number without affecting the scroll position(, or at least making the UX such that it does'nt seem confusing).

Any help or linking to a resource that solves this problem would be appreciated!

Here's a JSfiddle demo :

https://jsfiddle.net/veyydant/wcq9y367/16/

And the same as a code snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers: [
        1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10
    ],
   hasLoaded: false,
  },
  methods: {
    getRandomInt: function (max=10) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    },
    onUpEnd: function () {
        /* console.log('called') */
        this.numbers = [...this.numbers, this.getRandomInt()]
    },
    onDownEnd: function () {
      // console.log('called')
        this.numbers = [this.getRandomInt(), ...this.numbers]
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    document.querySelector('.list-body').scrollTop = 150;
    
    const top = document.querySelector('#top')
    this.upObserver = new IntersectionObserver(this.onUpEnd)
    this.upObserver.observe(top)
    
    const bottom = document.querySelector('#bottom')
    this.downObserver = new IntersectionObserver(this.onDownEnd)
    this.downObserver.observe(bottom)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.list-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.numbers {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: .5px dashed blue;
}

.loaders {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px grey dashed;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>List Items</h2>
  <div class="list-body">
    <div class="loaders" id="top">
      Top
    </div>
    <div class="numbers" v-for="number in numbers" :id="number">
      <span>{{ number }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="loaders" id="bottom">
      Bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```